# C++ removing non-alphabetic chars from beginning of a word

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream, erase-remove-idiom

I have the following code in a method of string type which reads words from a file, removes all non-alphabetic chars (as shown below) from the beginning of the word and returns them after it does so. After printing out the results in the main method, I have noticed that even though it should remove all the non-alphabetic characters from the beginning, it always still prints out 1, For example:
The list contains the words:

**There ,--once was a cute -;little rabbit and he got shot, end of story**

After applying the function, the output was:

**There -once was a cute ;little rabbit and he got shot, end of story**

```
inFile >> word;
    for(int i=0; i<word.size(); i++){
        if(word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z' || word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')  break;
        else word.erase(i,1);
    }
    return word;
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me just what the hell it is that i'm failing to see. I've tried all different functions e.g. **Erase(), isalpha()** etc. They all produce the same result when it shouldn't. What am I doing that is forbidding the last non-alphabetic character (at the beginning of a word) from being removed?
I tried the same to remove all punctuation marks at the end of a word but it would remove all except for one (again).

Thanks for your time

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you *do* know about the [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) function?

Comment: I actually just fixed it :p Didn't notice that i hadn't put i-- in erase

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah i do. I used it earlier but i forgot that the problem was within my loop values not the function which i've just noticed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop skips characters since you remove an item and continue. If you remove, you have to decrease `i` because the next letter is at the same position after erasing. Or you have to have a while loop for each position erasing that position until it is alpha or end, but decreasing `i` is simpler and less error prone.

Running the code on a debugger would've shown this problem in the logic immediately.

Comment: I will accept your answer even though I literally realized right after posting the question that I needed to do i-- in erase. :)